# How do you delete an aliased user

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

I am trying to delete an aliased user from a sql server 2000 database that was restored to sql server 2008 r2. Originally, I was attempting to convert the aliased user to a regular user, but it does not appear that I can do that, so now I am attempting to delete the user without deleting the login.

Comment: @DanGuzman Might as well post that as the answer, you got it in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sp_dropalias` do drop the legacy SQL Server 2000 user alias in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
 EXEC sp_dropalias N'<name-of-aliased-login-here>';
```

This stored procedure was [removed in SQL Server 2012 later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dropalias-transact-sql).